# Moving elements in a priority queue to a lower level

Tags: functional-programming, queue, priority-queue, sml, smlnj

I have a multi-level priority queue which is implemented as a list of (level:int, priority:int, 'a). The datatype looks like this:

```
datatype 'a queue = NONE | Q of (int * int * 'a) list;
```

Elements at lower level are at the front of the queue. Elements at same level are sorted on basis of priority. I have an enqueue function

So, if existing queue is:  `val a = Q [(3,2,"c"),(3,2,"d"),(5,2,"b"),(5,3,"a")],`
then, enqueue a 1 5 "e"
 gives

```
val a = Q [(1,5,"e"),(3,2,"c"),(3,2,"d"),(5,2,"b"),(5,3,"a")]
```

I have to write a function move which operates on a predicate p which moves all elements that satisfy the predicate p to a lower level queue within q.
That is : val move : ('a -> bool) -> 'a queue -> 'a queue
Definition as below won't work.

```
fun move pred (Q((l,p,v)::xs)) =  if (pred (v)) then enqueue (Q xs) (l-1) p v else (move pred (Q xs))
  | move pred (Q[]) = raise Empty
```

I have just started learning sml. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, having a constructor named `NONE` is bad, since it overwrites the
built-in option-type value of the same name. Secondly, you say that elements for
which the predicate satisfies should be moved to a lower level - is that level
always one less than its previous level?

Your `move` will not work because you apparently do not call it recursively
when `pred v` is true, only when it isn't. If you instead enqueue `(l,p,v)` into
a queue on which `move pred` is called recursively (i.e. `move pred (Q xs)`
rather than `Q xs`), perhaps it will work better.

Note also that this problem is ideal for solving through folding:

```
fun move pred (Q elems) =
    let fun enq ((l,p,v), q) = enqueue q (if pred v then l-1 else l) p v
    in foldl enq (Q []) elems end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to foldl and pointing my mistake regarding recursion. It was helpful indeed.

Comment: Essentially, you are re-adding every single element in a priority queue to a new empty queue. The fold version makes this a little more apparent since you specify `Q []` as the base. I believe, also, that your base case of raising an exception is insufficient as all recursion that removes a triple from a list will eventually reach the empty list. You probably want to re-think what it means to move all elements within an empty queue (it shouldn't be illegal).

Answer (score 0):

fun move pred (Q((l,p,v)::xs)) =  if (pred (v)) then enqueue (Q xs) (l-1) p v else enqueue (move pred (Q xs)) l p v
  | move pred (Q[]) = raise Empty
This also works !